# Create network in networkx from np.array

Tags: python, networkx

I've got a NumPy array (adjacency matrix) with 32.000 x 32.000 elements. Each of these elements is either 0 or a number ]0,1] (cosine similarity) - the weight of edge between node I and j. Each node has 120 neighbors, which means that in each row of the numpy there are 120 non-zero elements.

```
B = [[0. 0. 0. ... 0.43 0. ...]...]
```

When I create the network with:

```
network = nx.from_numpy_matrix(B, nx.DiGraph)
```

And print the node's degree:

```
network.degree
```

The result is:

```
DegreeView({0: 126, 1: 125, 2: 212, 3: 158, 4: 135, 5: 306, 6: 288, 7: 178, 8: 232, 9: 158, 10: 176, 11: 132, 12: 149, 13: 137, 14: 368, 15: 264, 16: 143, 17: 158, 18: 148, 19: 175, 20: 182, 21: 183, 22: 169, 23: 137, 24: 258, 25: 312, 26: 124, 27: 191, 28: 186, 29: 120, 30: 317, 31: 125, 32: 137, 33: 410, 34: 122, 35: 206, 36: 327, 37: 137, 38: 177, 39: 201, 40: 299, 41: 136, 42: 139, 43: 411, 44: 138, 45: 134, 46: 179, 47: 125, 48: 179, 49: 126, 50: 159, 51: 122, 52: 199, 53: 159, 54: 169, 55: 140, 56: 130, 57: 125, 58: 178, 59: 163, 60: 143, 61: 140, 62: 119, 63: 217, 64: 301, 65: 157, 66: 158, 67: 165, 68: 238, 69: 146, 70: 133, 71: 157, 72: 119, 73: 132, 74: 153, 75: 121, 76: 152, 77: 156, 78: 120, 79: 142, 80: 134, 81: 134, 82: 157, 83: 142, 84: 145, 85: 120, 86: 471, 87: 124, 88: 159, 89: 120, 90: 141, 91: 174, 92: 140, 93: 119, 94: 178, 95: 122, 96: 123, 97: 264, 98: 144, 99: 247, 100: 134, 101: 129, 102: 124, 103: 269, 104: 193...})
```

Why aren't my nodes ALL with degree 120?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a directed graph, so in this case "in degree" and "out degree" can be different. Out degree of node i would be the number of edges leaving node i, and in degree of node i is the number of edges onto node i.

When you say every node has degree 120, is it possible you mean the in or out degree should be 120? In networkx, [degree](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.degree.html#networkx.DiGraph.degree) is the sum of in and out degree for a directed graph. You can try [in degree](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.in_degree.html#networkx.DiGraph.in_degree) or [out degree](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.out_degree.html#networkx.DiGraph.out_degree) and see if that is what you want.